# Django + Haystack search user full name

Tags: django, django-views, django-haystack

I am setting up django-haystack and just have a question.

I use django-profiles, which allows me to add seperate information ie, city, gender etc.

I created a `search_indexes.py` for my `UserProfile` when I perform a search it only seems to return a users username result ie.

if I type `john` and the users username is john then it gets picked up, if I type `James` and the user `john`'s first name is `James` it does not return a result.

my search_indexes.py

```
from haystack.indexes import *
from haystack import site
from models import UserProfile

class UserProfileIndex(SearchIndex):
    text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    user = CharField(model_attr='user', use_template=True)

    def prepare_user(self, obj):
        return "%s <%s>" % (obj.user.get_full_name(), obj.user.email)

site.register(UserProfile, UserProfileIndex)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've only glanced over haystack code before, but isn't it because you're indexing on the model attribute "user" which means that will be the only field searched?

Answer (score 1):

What is the content of your UserProfile_text.txt (the SearchIndex template)?
It should be something like

```
{{ object.username }}
{{ object.firstname }}
...
```

with all the fields you want indexed from that model. See the [documentation](http://docs.haystacksearch.org/dev/tutorial.html#creating-searchindexes)

Answer (score 0):

the key point is

basicly you define what keywords you wantted to be indexed in your template of your index model

so please add fields that you need into your template file

Answer (score 0):

The template file should be like:

```
{{ object.user.first_name}}
{{ object.user.middle_name }}
```